# Recommendations for Master courses in Data Science in Europe

Tags: self-study

I am hoping somebody can help a (hopefully) future data scientist: I am looking for a Master course in data science at a school in Europe.

I have a Bachelor in Media Management (PR & Communication) and have then worked for several year as a market place manager for an international online retailer. I am now looking to pivot more into the data science part of this and am searching for a suitable master program.

Given that I do not come from a mathematics or computer science background I need a master program that focusses more on teaching how to apply known methods with existing tools rather than prepare me to implement the data science methods from scratch or to do in depth research on developing new machine learning algorithms.

Can somebody recommend any courses that would work for me? Many thanks in advance for your help.

---

Edit 1: I should probably add that I speak English and German.

Answer (score 0):

great to see you wanting to make a career change to DS.
If you want to go for a masters course, I would recommend that you try to get into a self-taught course to understand the fundamentals of programming and its concepts. There are many short courses on YT, Udemy or Coursera, I suggest not doing long courses as you will just get burnt out which I faced personally.

After that's done you can search for a good course where your requirements are met. I assume you are in Germany since you stated you speak German. This link has many good course recommendations on DS throughout EU: [DS Courses](https://www.masterstudies.com/MSc/Data-Science/Europe/)

But whichever course you take, make sure to check on the subjects first before looking at the university name only and most DS courses are taught fairly similar. A lot of masters courses teach from scratch as well which will be good for you. This is based on my personal experience.